# How to sort with logic

Tags: python

With four dictionaries `grandpa`, `dad`, `son_1` and `son_2`:

```
grandpa = {'name': 'grandpa', 'parents': []}
dad = {'name': 'dad', 'parents': ['grandpa']}
son_1 = {'name': 'son_1', 'parents': ['dad']}
son_2 = {'name': 'son_2', 'parents': ['dad']}
relatives = [son_1, grandpa, dad, son_2]
```

I want to write a function that sorts all these relatives in a "reverse" order.
So instead of `parents` there would be `children` list used. The oldest `grandpa` would be on the top level of `result` dictionary, the `dad` would be below with its `children` list storing the `son_1` and `son_2`:

```
def sortRelatives(relatives):
    # returns a resulted dictionary:
    # logic


result = sortRelatives(relatives)
print result
```

Which would print:

```
result = {'name': 'grandpa', 
            'children': [
                        {'name': 'dad', 
                        'children': [{'name': 'son_1', 'children': [] },
                                     {'name': 'son_2', 'children': [] }] }
                        ]

        }
```

How to make `sortRelatives` function perform a such sorting?

Comment: `The oldest grandpa would be on the top level of result dictionary` What is the field you're sorting on? For example, age is not included in your dictionary.

Comment: @ScottSkiles The one with empty `'parents'` I presume

Comment: I this example names are unique and there is only one parent. Is this a reasonable assumption to make or is your actual data very different from what you shared here?

Comment: I think the question needs significant clarification... (I did not downvote, however)

Comment: In this example, `relatives` is already in the correct order. Should we assume this is always the case?

Comment: This is not called sorting. It's a kind of lookup or mapping. I don't understand why it needs to be recursive? Where does that requirement come from? Is it homework?

Comment: I agree with Thomas, this does not need recursion it is a matter of looking up respective keys and assigning values.

Comment: If you have duplicate names this thing would possibly impossible to do with the current data-structure.

Comment: @ThomasWeller `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.`; I don't think it is any of the above. Just needs expanding. I was just noting it was not me that downvoted, as I appreciate it when, if my answers are downvoted, I'm given insight into why. I didn't want my comment to be interpreted a such. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: It is, perhaps, egregiously sloppy upon further consideration :-)

Comment: The goal is to produce the `result` dictionary (see the example). The order found in the list `relatives` can be random.

Comment: I didn't include the ages since I hoped that the names are self descriptive: `grandpa` is the oldest and the `sons` are being youngest.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I've just renamed the subject.

Comment: Just edited `relatives` list to disorder it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think is a viable yet simple solution is to first build a children dictionary that will map person names to their children. Then we can use that new data structure to build the output:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def children(relatives):
    children = defaultdict(list)
    for person in relatives:
        for parent in person['parents']:
            children[parent].append(person)
    return children
```

Another tool we can use is a function that would find the root of our genealogy:

```py
def genealogy_root(relatives):
    for person in relatives:
        if not person['parents']:
            return person
    raise TypeError("This doesn't look like a valid genealogy.")
```

That will help us locating the person that has no parent, and will therefore be the root of our genealogy-tree. Now that we have all the necessary tools we just need to build the output:

```py
def build_genealogy(relatives):
    relatives_children = children(relatives)

    def sub_genealogy(current_person):
        name = current_person['name']
        return dict(
            name=name,
            children=[sub_genealogy(child) for child in relatives_children[name]] 
        )

    root = genealogy_root(relatives)
    return sub_genealogy(root)

result = build_genealogy(relatives)
print(result)
```

Which outputs:

```
{
  'name': 'grandpa', 'children': [
     {'name': 'dad', 'children': [
         {'name': 'son_1', 'children': []}, 
         {'name': 'son_2', 'children': []}
     ]}
  ]
}
```

Note that as I said in the comments, this is only working because there are no name duplicates. If several persons share the same name, you will have to have a better data-structure as input. For example, you may want to have something like:

```py
grandpa = {'name': 'grandpa', 'parents': []}
dad = {'name': 'dad', 'parents': [grandpa]}
son_1 = {'name': 'son_1', 'parents': [dad]}
son_2 = {'name': 'son_2', 'parents': [dad]}
relatives = [grandpa, dad, son_1, son_2]
```